# Ionic Android build stopped working

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

My Ionic/Cordova app has all of a sudden stopped building on Android after updating the Ionic and Cordova CLI. I've spent the last 2 days searching Google for a solution but I couldn't find anything that has helped. I'm assuming it's something to do with Cordova now using Gradle to build instead of Apache Ant. My Android SDK and build tools are all up to version 22, Gradle 2.2, Ant 1.9.4, JDK 8.

**Other details:**
Cordova CLI: 5.1.1
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.3
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.7

When I run ionic build android, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 128

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> No match found

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.426 secs

/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: /platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: /platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
```

Comment: did you try to remove the platform and add it back?

Comment: Yes, I've done it quite a few times but still no luck

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You might need to set the android-versionCode in your config.xml file. I had a similar issue that was resolved by changing the code from "0.0.1" to "1". Apparently Android wants a single integer value.

In my config.xml I had to change this:

```
<widget id="com.acme.appname" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="0.0.1" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

to this:

```
<widget id="com.acme.appname" version="0.0.1" android-versionCode="1" ios-CFBundleVersion="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

[**android-versionCode**](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! They should update this here though: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html

Comment: Just had a similar problem, same error, with the difference that I did not have that value set, once I set it, it started working again :)

Comment: Here's the spec on how to turn a semver into a version acceptable for Android: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-the-version-code