# ionic build android stopped working

Tags: android, ionic-framework

In my Windows 7 machine, I had `ionic build android` working. I could build the apk, deploy/debug with `ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs` etc. All of sudden (as in I don't know what possibly could have caused this), the `ionic build android` stopped working. When I try to run it, it freezes in this screen:

```
ajunior@DES6635D C:\src\to\my\project
> ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\src\to\my\project\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\src\to\my\project
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\src\to\my\project\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
```

Event after an hour or so, no output is given; I have to manually break the process with <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Any suggestions? The strange thing is that this was working this morning (and all the other days for the last two weeks), so I believe that it's not related to PATH, Android SDK or anything like that. Nothing was installed, uninstalled or updated in this time. I already tried restarting the machine, but that also didn't work.

Comment: I also tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31414838/ionic-android-build-stopped-working), to no avail.

Comment: ```ionic platform remove android``` + ```ionic platform add android``` didn't do the trick, either.

Comment: Strangely enough, running manually ```C:\src\to\my\project\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat``` (on the terminal, ```cd```-ing to the directory and running ```build.bat```) worked. For some reason ```ionic build android``` command is become freezed on the way calling this bat file.

Comment: Interesting. Running ```C:\src\to\my\project\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat``` on the terminal (directly, pasting the command) does not work, but as I stated above ```cd```-ing to the directory and running ```build.bat``` works.

Comment: Ended up backing up the ```www``` folder and creating another project from scratch. That worked. :(

Answer (score 0):

When in path via cmd run: `cordova build android --ant`

It will build like that (you must have ant installed of course).

Then: `cordova run android`

If cordova run android gives issues just fetch the apk from the build folder in your ionic project: 
`platforms\android\build\outputs\apk`

Then allow cellphone to accept *Unknown Sources*, copy the file to your phone and install.